# visual studio code editor all html tags are red since last update

Tags: visual-studio-code

hi since the last update to 1.6.1 all my html files appear with red tags, I have tried disabling the few extensions I have to no avail. Anyone run into this recently? thanks in advance

VSCode Version: Code 1.6.1 (9e4e44c, 2016-10-13T16:21:53.542Z)
OS Version: Windows_NT ia32 10.0.14393
Extensions: abusaidm.html-snippets-0.0.17, anseki.vscode-color-0.1.11, dbaeumer.jshint-0.10.15, donjayamanne.githistory-0.1.0, donjayamanne.python-0.4.2, DotJoshJohnson.xml-1.6.0, HookyQR.beautify-0.4.1, lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter-0.2.1, ms-vscode.csharp-1.4.1, ms-vscode.Theme-TomorrowKit-0.1.3, msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-1.2.1, robertohuertasm.vscode-icons-3.0.5, Zignd.html-css-class-completion-1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

received from vss code team:
The underlying grammar has changed that creates the syntax highlighting tokens. We are now using standard text mate grammar, generated scopes should be similar, but changes can occur. Looks like the Tommorow night Bright color theme is sensitive to these change.
Nothing I can do from our side, we are not authoring neither the grammar not the color theme.

confirm disabling the theme worked